# What does $ \int a$ ^ $ b $ mean?

Tags: calculus, notation

Im slightly familiar with calculus.

I can do some integrals , integral equation and differential equations.

Im also slightly familiar with matrices.

I have seen this symbol ^ in the computation of the determinant and i understand that.

But im not sure what that symbol ^ means in calculus !

In particular things like

$\int a$ ^ $ b$

I think i have seen it used in some books for convolution but I assume that is NOT the standard meaning.

Im no expert in topology , measure theory , statistics or set theory so if possible , give me a simple calculus explaination please.

---

Edit

As said in the comments

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Wedge_product

But that is for multivariable calculus.

Im looking for single variable calculus here.

Sorry shoud have said that immediately.

Maybe another meaning than the link above might also help me.

---

Comment: probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Wedge_product

Comment: Oh yes. Well that seems complicated , but in general that is for multivariable calculus right ? I have seen ^ in single variable calculus and that really confused me ! ( no source sorry )

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) in differential geometry?

Comment: @mick, could it be [meet and join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet)?